# Getting next element in a table javascript

Tags: javascript, html

https://jsfiddle.net/en6jh7pa/1/

I am having issues grabbing the next element, it is returning null for the next element.

I am passing "this? as `onclick` and I assumed that you could use this to grab the next element but it seems that it instead returns null

Thanks for your help

```js
    function assignnames(checkboxelement){
    
    checkboxelement.setAttribute("name", "checkbox");
    var value1box = checkboxelement.nextSibling;
    value1box.setAttribute("name", "notnull");
    var value2box = checkboxelement.nextElementSibling;
    value2box.setAttribute("name", "notnull");
    alert("done");
    
    }
```

```html
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>
        Checkbox
      </th>
      <th>
        value1
      </th>
      <th>
        value2
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="assignnames(this)" id="checkbox1"/>
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="text" name="" id="fname1">
      </td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" name="" id="lname1">
      </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: I get a script error. It's likely in most browsers that `checkboxelement.nextSibling` is a an empty text node, not an element, so it doesn't have a *setAttribute* method.

Comment: thats what i'm seeing as well, how could I grab the input boxes? dynamically because the table will have multiple rows

Comment: The simplest way is to wrap the table in a form and give the inputs names, then you can access them as named properties of the form, or as part of the form's [*elements* collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements). Or you might access them using a selector based on the table, table section or row they're in. Whatever you think is best.

Comment: Checkbox input element is only node inside td, so nextSibling correcly showing empty, another input box is in different td

Comment: Unfortunately they cannot have names because they ARE wrapped in a form and i only want the ones that are checked to be submitted so I am using a "hacky" way to add names so that they will submit on the form after it is checked. @crack_iT yes you are correct now i am understanding, is there anyway to jump to the next td?

Comment: You can try to find next sibling of its parent node(td), then find child element of next td to get second input element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the text inputs in the same row, you can go up to the row, then use a selector to get the inputs, e.g.

```js
function getParent(node, tag) {
  var tag = tag.toLowerCase();
  do {
    if (node.tagName.toLowerCase() == tag) {
      return node;
    }
    node = node.parentNode;
  } while (node && node.tagName && node.parentNode)
  return null;
}

function getInputs(evt) {
  var row = getParent(this, 'tr');
  var inputs;
  if (row) {
    inputs = row.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
  }
  console.log(`Found ${inputs.length} text inputs, node is ${this.checked? '':'not '}checked.`);
}

window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('checkbox1').addEventListener('click', getInputs, false);
};
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr><th>Checkbox
      <th>value1
      <th>value2
  <tr><td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
      <td><input type="text" name="" id="fname1">
      <td><input type="text" name="" id="lname1">
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the inputs to be siblings, they would all have to be within the same `<td>`, sharing a singular parent. With them spread out across multiple table cells, they would be considered *cousins* instead (keeping with the family tree metaphor), which doesn't have a similar shortcut property.

You can still use `nextElementSibling` along the way between inputs, but you'll also have to move up and back down between *generations*.

```js
function assignnames(checkboxelement){
    checkboxelement.setAttribute("name", "checkbox");

    var value1box = checkboxelement
        .parentElement      // up a generation the checkbox' parent <td>
        .nextElementSibling // then to the next <td> in the row
        .firstElementChild; // and back down a generation to the next input
                            // the last step could also be: .querySelector('input')

    value1box.setAttribute("name", "notnull");

    var value2box = value1box
        .parentElement
        .nextElementSibling
        .firstElementChild;

    value2box.setAttribute("name", "notnull");

    alert("done");
}
```

```html
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>
        Checkbox
      </th>
      <th>
        value1
      </th>
      <th>
        value2
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="assignnames(this)" id="checkbox1"/>
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="text" name="" id="fname1">
      </td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" name="" id="lname1">
      </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```